# Set array values in javascript from JSTL code

Tags: javascript, jsp, jstl

I have a code that looks like this:

In AnalyzeUserClient.jsp:

```
<c:set var="arrayList"><%= (ArrayList<String>)request.getSession().getAttribute("arrayList") %></c:set>
var sessionId = [];
<c:forEach items=${arrayList} var="id">
sessionId.push("${id}"); // add them one at a time, assuming string values
</c:forEach>
```

However,this line:

```
    sessionId.push("${id}");
```

does not seem to be passing the values into the array "sessionId" (I viewed the source code on browser).So the question is,what can I do to pass the values into the array?


EDIT:I just realised that there are some problems as JSTL is server-side and JavaScript is client-side.So is there a workaround on it?

Comment: Regarding your edit about server-side working together with client-side, if the intention is to produce JS that populates the `sessionId` array and then use it only on the client-side then that doesn't matter. (It only becomes a problem if your server-side code tries to use the array too.) You should be able to use server-side code to output JS that populates an array - though I'd consider structuring it in a way that puts the values directly in the array literal `[]` rather than using `.push()`.

Comment: I tried doing: "sessionId["${id}"];" as well,but it is still not working.Is there another way to resolve this?

Answer (score 8):

Don't mix EL and scriptlets. In fact, forget about scriptlets completely:

```
var sessionId = [];
<c:forEach items="${sessionScope.arrayList}" var="id">
    sessionId.push("${id}"); 
</c:forEach>
```

Note though that this will generate invalid JavaScript if one of the IDs happens to contain a double quote. So you'd better JavaScript-escape the IDs before, in your controller. And I would suggest a completely different approach: serialize the list of IDs to a JSON string in your controller, and store this JSON string in request attribute. The JSP page will just need

```
var sessionId = ${jsonEncodedSessionIds};
```

which will translate to the following generated code:

```
var sessionId = ["id1", "id2"];
```

Comment: On the browser the line:"sessionId.push("${id}");" becomes "sessionId.push("");",is it related to the problems of server and client-side coding?

Comment: No. It just means that the session ID stored in your list is null or is an empty string.

Comment: If that is the case,why does the browser unable to read the JSTL array values into the javascript array?

Comment: I don't understand your question. `sessionId.push("")` is valid JavaScript. It adds an empty string to the `sessionId` array.

Comment: What I meant is that why is it still adding an empty string instead of the values of the JSTL array?

Comment: It **does** add the values of the JSTL list. But this list contains a null element or an empty string. If it shouldn't contain that, then you have a bug in the Java code which populates this list.

Comment: Ok,I will need to check it out.