# Unable to set JSTL array values in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jstl

Continued from this question: [Set array values in javascript from JSTL code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13190306/set-array-values-in-javascript-from-jstl-code).

I tried using the solution the other member of the forum suggested to me,but it still does not seem to be working.As in,the line:

```
sessionId.push("${id}");
```

on the Eclipse IDE becomes:

```
 sessionId.push("");
```

on the browser(when I do a view-source).

That member also told me there could be a null element or empty string in the array,does the array:

```
"["Environment", "1", "Education", "1", "Disaster_Accident", "1", "Hospitality_Recreation", "2", "Labor", "1", "Human Interest", "3"]"
```

considered to have a null element or string?

Comment: Why does your "array" have double-quotes around it? Typo in your question, or something weird in your real code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have a syntax error somewhere. Please try using this demonstration page. It works for me in IE8 browser.

```
<%@ page import="java.util.*,java.io.*" %>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%> 
<%
   //scriptlet is for testing,
   List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
   list.add("Environment");
   list.add("1");
   list.add("Education");
   list.add("1");
   list.add("Disaster_Accident");
   request.setAttribute("arrayList", list);
%>
<script>
var sessionId = [];
<c:forEach items="${arrayList}" var="id">
       sessionId.push("${id}");
</c:forEach>
alert(sessionId);
</script>
```

Comment: I guess I forgot to import a JSTL jar file,thank you for your solution.